# Java - looking for more efficient way to code class methods

Tags: java, class, performance

I am creating a program that automates creation of player characters. Below is my `PlayerCharacter` class. I have noticed that I repeat many operations on different variables.

```
public class PlayerCharacter {

    int strength, dexterity, constitution, intelligence, wisdom, charisma;
    int[] strRolls, dexRolls, conRolls, intRolls, wisRolls, charRolls;

    public void generateAbilityScoresMethod1() {

        strRolls = new int[3];
        dexRolls = new int[3];
        conRolls = new int[3];
        intRolls = new int[3];
        wisRolls = new int[3];
        charRolls = new int[3];

        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

            strRolls[i] = dice.Dice.D6.getNewRoll();
            strength += strRolls[i];

            dexRolls[i] = dice.Dice.D6.getNewRoll();
            dexterity += dexRolls[i];

            conRolls[i] = dice.Dice.D6.getNewRoll();
            constitution += conRolls[i];

            intRolls[i] = dice.Dice.D6.getNewRoll();
            intelligence += intRolls[i];

            wisRolls[i] = dice.Dice.D6.getNewRoll();
            wisdom += wisRolls[i];

            charRolls[i] = dice.Dice.D6.getNewRoll();
            charisma += charRolls[i];

        }


    }

    public int getStrength() {
        return strength;
    }

    public void printStrRolls() {
        System.out.println("Str: roll 1 = " + strRolls[0]);
        System.out.println("Str: roll 2 = " + strRolls[1]);
        System.out.println("Str: roll 3 = " + strRolls[2]);
    }

    public int getDexterity() {
        return dexterity;
    }

    public void printDexRolls() {
        System.out.println("Dex: roll 1 = " + dexRolls[0]);
        System.out.println("Dex: roll 2 = " + dexRolls[1]);
        System.out.println("Dex: roll 3 = " + dexRolls[2]);
    }

    public int getConsitution() {
        return constitution;
    }

    public void printConRolls() {
        System.out.println("Con: roll 1 = " + conRolls[0]);
        System.out.println("Con: roll 2 = " + conRolls[1]);
        System.out.println("Con: roll 3 = " + conRolls[2]);
    }

    public int getIntelligence() {
        return intelligence;
    }

    public void printIntRolls() {
        System.out.println("Int: roll 1 = " + intRolls[0]);
        System.out.println("Int: roll 2 = " + intRolls[1]);
        System.out.println("Int: roll 3 = " + intRolls[2]);
    }

    public int getWisdom() {
        return wisdom;
    }

    public void printWisRolls() {
        System.out.println("Wis: roll 1 = " + wisRolls[0]);
        System.out.println("Wis: roll 2 = " + wisRolls[1]);
        System.out.println("Wis: roll 3 = " + wisRolls[2]);
    }

    public int getCharisma() {
        return charisma;
    }

    public void printCharRolls() {
        System.out.println("Char: roll 1 = " + charRolls[0]);
        System.out.println("Char: roll 2 = " + charRolls[1]);
        System.out.println("Char: roll 3 = " + charRolls[2]);
    }

    public void printAbilities() {
        System.out.println("Str = " + getStrength());
        System.out.println("Dex = " + getDexterity());
        System.out.println("Con = " + getConsitution());
        System.out.println("Int = " + getIntelligence());
        System.out.println("Wis = " + getWisdom());
        System.out.println("Char = " + getCharisma());
    }

}
```

How can I accomplish the same tasks in a more efficient way?

Comment: why do you store the Rolls arrays anyway??

Comment: Mostly curiosity to see how my dice rolls are going.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may declare a class `Ability` and make `strength`, `dexterity`, ... instances thereof. The following snippet might be a start:

```
class Ability {

    private final int[] rolls;
    private int value;

    public Ability(int dice) {
        rolls = new int[dice];
    }

    public int roll() {
        value = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < rolls.length; i++) {
            rolls[i] = dice.Dice.D6.getNewRoll();
            value += rolls[i];
        }
        return value;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void printRolls() {
        // ... tbd ...
    }

}
```

You can the use the abilities like ...

```
Ability strength;
strength = new Ability(3);
strength.roll(); // get new value
System.out.println(strength.getValue()); // e.g. print
strength.printRolls(); // e.g. print rolls
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
public void printRolls( String label, int[] rolls) {
    System.out.println(label + ": roll 1 = " + rolls[0]);
    System.out.println(label + ": roll 2 = " + rolls[1]);
    System.out.println(label + ": roll 3 = " + rolls[2]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can cut down repeated code line this

```
enum Attribute {
   Str, Con, Dex, Int, Wis, Cha
}

class PlayerCharacter {
   static final Random rand = new Random();
   static final Attribute[] ATTRS = Attributes.values();
   final int[] attr = new int[ATTRS.length];

   PlayerCharacter() {
       for(int i = 0; i < attr.length; i++)
           attr[i] = rand.nextInt(6) + rand.nextInt(6) + rand.nextInt(6) + 3;
   }

   public int getAttr(Attribute attr) {
       return attrs[attr.ordinal()];
   }

   public void printAbilities() {
        for(int i = 0; i < ATTRS.length; i++)
           System.out.println(ATTRS[i]+ " = " + attrs[i]);
  }
```

Note: you may want any other attributes like HP, AC, Max HP, Level, XP, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I would do there is to create a static dice rolling method which returns the array you need, so you can generate dice roll arrays for any type of dice:

```
public static int[] roll(int numberOfDice, int sidesOnEachDie) {
    int[] result = new int[numberOfDice];
    for(int i = 0; i < numberOfDice; ++i) {
        result[i] = 1 + (int) Math.floor(Math.random() *
                (double) sidesOnEachDie);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Then you can call, for example:

```
intRolls = roll(3, 6);
```

which will give the result of rolling 3D6 in an int array.

Comment: My rolls are handled by a Dice enum class.

Comment: Is it too late to add the option to return multiple rolls in one go to that Dice class? It would remove the need to add for loops in the main flow of your code if you could have the Dice class return multiple results with one method call.

Comment: That is certainly a viable option, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

You could keep all your properties in an int[]. So rather than having strength, dexterity, constitution, intelligence, wisdom, charisma as separate variables have one

```
int[] characteristics;
```

then 0 would be strength; 1 would be dexterity and so on.

To keep the roll values you would need a int[][].

Answer (score 0):

This is less code; it is not "more efficient" in CPU use or memory use, but makes the code shorter to write and read.  I assume dice rolls are random regardless of their order.

```
package example;

public class PlayerCharacter
{

  int strength, dexterity, constitution, intelligence, wisdom, charisma;
  int[] strRolls, dexRolls, conRolls, intRolls, wisRolls, charRolls;

  private int getScore(Dice d, int[] storage)
  {
    for (int i=0; i<storage.length; i++)
    {
      storage[i] = d.getNewRoll();
    }
    int result = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<storage.length; i++) { result += storage[i]; }

  }

  public void generateAbilityScoresMethod1()
  {

    strRolls = new int[3];
    dexRolls = new int[3];
    conRolls = new int[3];
    intRolls = new int[3];
    wisRolls = new int[3];
    charRolls = new int[3];

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
      strength      = getScore(dice.Dice.D6, strRolls);
      dexterity     = getScore(dice.Dice.D6, dexRolls);
      constitution  = getScore(dice.Dice.D6, conRolls);
      intelligence  = getScore(dice.Dice.D6, intRolls);
      wisdom        = getScore(dice.Dice.D6, wisRolls);
      charisma      = getScore(dice.Dice.D6, charRolls);

    }

  }

  public int getStrength()
  {
    return strength;
  }

  private void printArrayRolls(String label, int[] rolls)
  {
    for (int i=0; i < rolls.length; i++)
    {
      System.out.println(label + ": roll " + rolls[i]);
    }
  }

  public void printStrRolls()
  {
    printArrayRolls("Str", strRolls);
  }

  public int getDexterity()
  {
    return dexterity;
  }

  public void printDexRolls()
  {
    printArrayRolls("Dex", dexRolls);
  }

  public int getConsitution()
  {
    return constitution;
  }

  public void printConRolls()
  {
    printArrayRolls("Con", conRolls);
  }

  public int getIntelligence()
  {
    return intelligence;
  }

  public void printIntRolls()
  {
    printArrayRolls("Int", intRolls);
  }

  public int getWisdom()
  {
    return wisdom;
  }

  public void printWisRolls()
  {
    printArrayRolls("Wis", wisRolls);
  }

  public int getCharisma()
  {
    return charisma;
  }

  public void printCharRolls()
  {
    printArrayRolls("Char", charRolls);
  }

  public void printAbilities()
  {
    System.out.println("Str = " + getStrength());
    System.out.println("Dex = " + getDexterity());
    System.out.println("Con = " + getConsitution());
    System.out.println("Int = " + getIntelligence());
    System.out.println("Wis = " + getWisdom());
    System.out.println("Char = " + getCharisma());
  }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is less code; it is not "efficient" in CPU use or memory use, but makes the code shorter to write and read.  I assume dice rolls are random regardless of their order.

```
package example;

public class PlayerCharacter
{

  int strength, dexterity, constitution, intelligence, wisdom, charisma;
  int[] strRolls, dexRolls, conRolls, intRolls, wisRolls, charRolls;

  private int getScore(Dice d, int[] storage)
  {
    for (int i=0; i<storage.length; i++)
    {
      storage[i] = d.getNewRoll();
    }
    int result = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<storage.length; i++) { result += storage[i]; }

  }

  public void generateAbilityScoresMethod1()
  {

    strRolls = new int[3];
    dexRolls = new int[3];
    conRolls = new int[3];
    intRolls = new int[3];
    wisRolls = new int[3];
    charRolls = new int[3];

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
      strength      = getScore(dice.Dice.D6, strRolls);
      dexterity     = getScore(dice.Dice.D6, dexRolls);
      constitution  = getScore(dice.Dice.D6, conRolls);
      intelligence  = getScore(dice.Dice.D6, intRolls);
      wisdom        = getScore(dice.Dice.D6, wisRolls);
      charisma      = getScore(dice.Dice.D6, charRolls);

    }

  }

  public int getStrength()
  {
    return strength;
  }

  private void printArrayRolls(String label, int[] rolls)
  {
    for (int i=0; i < rolls.length; i++)
    {
      System.out.println(label + ": roll " + rolls[i]);
    }
  }

  public void printStrRolls()
  {
    printArrayRolls("Str", strRolls);
  }

  public int getDexterity()
  {
    return dexterity;
  }

  public void printDexRolls()
  {
    printArrayRolls("Dex", dexRolls);
  }

  public int getConsitution()
  {
    return constitution;
  }

  public void printConRolls()
  {
    printArrayRolls("Con", conRolls);
  }

  public int getIntelligence()
  {
    return intelligence;
  }

  public void printIntRolls()
  {
    printArrayRolls("Int", intRolls);
  }

  public int getWisdom()
  {
    return wisdom;
  }

  public void printWisRolls()
  {
    printArrayRolls("Wis", wisRolls);
  }

  public int getCharisma()
  {
    return charisma;
  }

  public void printCharRolls()
  {
    printArrayRolls("Char", charRolls);
  }

  public void printAbilities()
  {
    System.out.println("Str = " + getStrength());
    System.out.println("Dex = " + getDexterity());
    System.out.println("Con = " + getConsitution());
    System.out.println("Int = " + getIntelligence());
    System.out.println("Wis = " + getWisdom());
    System.out.println("Char = " + getCharisma());
  }

}
```